# What is the chronological order of events mentioned in Devi Mahtmya/Durga Shaptshati?

Tags: yuga, devi, shaktism, markandeya-purana, durga-saptasati

Devi Mahatmya or Durga Shaptshati is one of the most important Shakta scriptures. It is present in Markandeya Purana. Basically it tells the story of King Suratha and a Vaishya who go to Medha Rishi where they learn about Devi Shakti and her various forms.

I want to know the chronological order of the events mentioned in this text. The main events of which I want to know order that is MahaYuga/Yuga/Manuvantara are-

- King Suratha being defeated by his enemies leaving for forest where he find a vaishya who was forced to leave his house. Both of them go to Medha Muni's Ashram where even violent animals are living peacefully with other beings. I want to know when this incident happened.
- Sri Vishnu slaying Madhu Kaitabh demons.
- Mother Goddess slaying mahisasura.
- Mother Goddess slaying Raktabija,Dhumralochan and other demons ultimately killing Shumbh-Nishumbh.
- Mother Goddess predicting Her future incarnations of Raktadantika and Shakambari among others.
  RaktaDantika will be an incarnation of Devi to kill asuras who are torturing Sages in Himalayas.
  And Shakambari being a incarnation for saving the world after 100 years period without any rain.
  I want to know when will these incarnations of Devi come to earth.
- King Suratha and Vaishya ultimately praying to Mother Goddess. Mother Goddess gives boon to King Suratha to be Manu and Vaishya was given Moksha. I want to know King Suratha will be Manu in which Yuga/Manunvatara.

I want to know the Yuga/Manuvantara in which the above events took place.

Comment: If you go on “The Sanskrit Channel” on YT they have a playlist for Durga Saptashati with brief overview type explanation of the events. Lots of other info on that channel too (plz disregard this comment if you’ve already seen it :)

Comment: The events of King Suratha heard Devi Mahatmya is happened in Swarochisha Manvantara. King Suratha was reborn as Savarni Manu, so He will be manu at end of present Vaivasvata Manvantara. And, Vishnu was slew Madhu-Kaitabha at start of Kalpa.

Answer (score 1):

1. King Suratha lived on Svarochisha Manvantara. So, the Devi Mahatmya is narreted to him at the time. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57221.html) of Devi Mahatmya mention that, he lived during Svarochisha Manvantara.

> 5-21. Vyāsa said :-- O King! In days of yore in Svārociṣa Manvantara there was a king, named Suratha, very liberal-minded and devoted to govern well his subjects.

2. Lord Vishnu slew Madhu-Kaitabha at start of Brahma's day (Kalpa). Many Puranas mentioned this.
3. The events of slaying of Mahishasura and slaying of Chanda, Munda, Raktabija and Sumbha-Nisumbha was possibly happened at Svayambhuva or Svarochisha Manvantara.
4. King Suratha was reborn as Savarni Manu. So, He will become Manu at Savarni Manvantara.

Hope it helps.